# Unable to install Canon Pixma MG3250 printer drivers in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, 64-bit, printer, network-printer

When I install the drivers, I get an driver installation failed error message.

The network tool finds the printer, but there is no driver.

The printer can print from another Windows 7  machine, so it's a problem with my PC.

Comment: What drivers are you installing? The ones from included CD or some driver downloaded from Canon's website?

Comment: Drivers from the website. I lost the CD.

Comment: What is the exact error message you receive?  You say you got the driver from Canon, can you provide the exact link/location you got them from, so we know which driver you're attempting to use? like did you get the actual Windows 8.1 driver for the right bit-level (32 or 64) of your OS install?